# "Simple" Vector SIMD operations in Assembly ( v1 + v2 -> v3 ) called from C#

Tags: c#, assembly, x86-64, sse

I am having thought time performing - i believe - simple operation in Assembly, its required for me to use SIMD operation in Assembly for my Uni project.

I have Windows Forms Application in which i import the function from Assembly:

```cs
   [DllImport(@"C:\Neon\x64\Debug\JANeonLib.dll")]
   public static extern void AsmAdd(ref int[] a, ref int[] b, ref int[] result);
```

In the C# caller I have:

```cs
   int[] Toned = new int[width * height * 3];
   int[] Bumped = new int[width * height * 3];
   int[] Final = new int[width * height * 3];

   // ... ( filling the Toned and Bumped with data )

   AsmAdd(ref Toned, ref Bumped, ref Final); // <- running the assembly code through dll library, here is where the code fails
```

In assembly itself i have simple:

```
.code

AsmAdd proc
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp

    mov rax, rsi
    movaps xmm0, [rax]  

    mov rax, rdi 
    movaps xmm1, [rax] ; <- debugger here says i access memory?

    addps xmm0, xmm1 

    mov rax, r8
    movaps [rax], xmm0    

    pop rbp
    ret

AsmAdd endp

end
```

What im trying to achive is kinda: `for( i from 0 to size ) result[i] = a[i] + b[i];`

I am not good with Assembly, i will be honesty here, it might be issue with byte/word/dword/qword sizes? I have no clue.

Don't want to make it too long, but i could also use subtraction and multiplying each element of vector, also on the other note, multiplying each value in vector by constant.

Comment: Windows calling convention uses RCX, RDX, R8, R9 for parameters. Linux uses RDI, RSI, RDX, RCX, R8, R9. You seem to be using neither convention. You're also using `movaps` when there's no guarantee the data is aligned, and you don't actually have a loop so you'll only process 128 bits.

Comment: @interjay
OH MY GOD
you are right about the loop, it works now, thank you a bilion!!!
My mind somehow set into thought that it will do entire array, even if its 1000000 values long xD

Comment: Are you supposed to pass arrays like this: `ref int[] a`? That's relatively odd and results in a double indirection

Comment: Also note that you use floating point instructions when your array holds integers.  Change this to integer instruction (`movdqu`, `paddd`) and it should work much better.

Comment: Where is the ```mov rsp, rbp``` at the end?

Comment: @ImanAbdollahzadeh: It's not needed (or optimized away if you want to look at it that way) because RSP is still equal to RBP at that point.  Of course, it wasn't necessary to touch RBP or RSP at all in this function, the whole stack frame setup is just a waste of instructions for simple functions that only need registers.

Comment: `mov rax, rsi` / `movaps xmm0, [rax]` is a confusing an slower way to write `movaps xmm0, [rsi]`.  It's much easier to read asm if access to different arrays use different pointer registers, and it's a waste of an instruction to copy the register.

Comment: Am I missing something or not? Why do you use ```MOVAPS```  and not ```MOVUPS``` while there is no alignment on values?